# Can I disable default behavior from right click on IFrame from external source?

Tags: angular, iframe, powerbi, contextmenu

I know similar questions have been asked to this in the past but I wanted to see If my circumstances were any different and if there has been any development on this topic since most of these QAs have been asked a few years back.

On my website we are embedding a power-bi report within the angular application. The html locally just holds to power bi report and we get the iframe externally from powerbi.
Users are able to right click on the iframe for report specific functionality. However, when the user right clicks both the iframe right click menu comes up and the default browsers right click menu. Is there a way to just disable the browsers right click menu?

I have tried contextmenu disabling and other suggested responses on previous questions. I can disable the right click on the entire web page expect on the iframe report itself.

This is my html where the report is embedded.

```
   <div class="col-report" id="reportContainer" [style.width.px]="contentWidth" [ngStyle]="iframeEvents">
        <powerbi-report  *ngIf="(reportConfig && reportConfig.accessToken)" #reportEmbed [embedConfig]="reportConfig" [cssClassName]="reportClass" [phasedEmbedding]="phasedEmbeddingFlag" [eventHandlers]="eventHandlersMap" id="powerbiFrame">
        </powerbi-report>
    </div>
```